# Is the sequence $u_n=n\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}(1-2^{-i})^n$ convergent when $n\to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

#### Problem

Is the sequence $u_n=n\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}(1-2^{-i})^n$ convergent when $n\to \infty$?

#### Progress

If $i\leq \log n$ then $(1-2^{-i})^n<e^{-\frac{n}{2^i}}$. Unfortunately, I do not know what to do next

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: If $i\leq \log n$ then $(1-2^{-i})^n<e^{-\frac{n}{2^i}}$ Unfortunately, I do not know what to do next

Comment: Added the remark to the body of question, so it does not get closed... also, why type `\longrightarrow`, when `\to` is so much shorter and makes sense syntactically?

Answer (score 2):

This sequence does not converge. You can find the argument in *Tossing Coins Until All Show Heads*, American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 101, January 1994, p.78-80.  There are more details [in my answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/a-recurrence-that-wiggles/4378#4378)

Comment: Nice, +1. For those without access to the full text (such as me at the moment), the sequence exhibits an oscillating behavior between two finite positive limits, right?

Comment: @Did Yes that is correct. I've added a link to another MSE answer   of mine with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Some numerics may help. According to a rough calculation of the sum (capping the summation at $i=10^4$), it seems that the sum does not diverge, but stabilizes close to

$$u_n \approx 1.44268$$

[image]

A closer look at the graph shows that it oscillates around this value

[image]

Comment: Nice (especially your choice to show *two* graphs...).